# Why is $x^3 + 3x + 2$ irreducible by plugging in elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The polynomial $x^3+3x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. I get that it must take the form of $(x-a)g(x)$ where $a$ is a zero,but my book plugged in elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ to show no zeros, but I thought the indeterminate $x$ can take any value, not just $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: $x$ can take on any value, but $x+5$ takes on the same value as $x$ within $\Bbb Z_5$ for all polynomials.

Comment: Um, so say $a \notin Z_5$, whats stopping $(a - a)g(a) = 0$? Is what I don't get.

Comment: For example, $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[x]$, even though there is a root in $\mathbb C$. This is because there is no root in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, oh right $a \in Z_5$ for the factor theorem to work, I forgot about that...thanks

Comment: @Hawk If $a\not\in \mathbb Z_5$ then $x-a\not\in\mathbb Z_5[x]$. So the resulting factorization is not a factorization in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. For example, $5$ is a prime integer, even though $5=(2+i)(2-i)$ is a factorization of $5$ somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking a monic factor of your polynomial of degree $1$ in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. This means a polynomial of the form $x-a$ for some $a\in \mathbb Z_5$.

It is certainly possible for $\mathbb Z_5$ to be included in a ring where this polynomial has a root. That doesn't contradict this polynomial being irreducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

For example:

- $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[x]$, even though it has roots in $\mathbb C$.
- $x^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ even though it has a root in $\mathbb R$.
- $5$ is irreducible in the integers, but $5=(2+i)(2-i)$ is a factorization in the Gaussian integers.

Being irreducible in one ring $R$ does not imply being irreducible in all other rings that contain (an image of) $R$.